# undo / redo software pattern for split merge

Tags: design-patterns

I have a somewhat complex piece of genomics software where I allow undo and redo operations.    If I have an element A, I can move it to A0, A1, A2, A3, etc. and move it around to any point in its history.  This is easy.

What I'm trying to figured out is the concept of splits and merges.  If I have A0 and B0 and, I can merge them into A1 and go back and forth fairly easily.  However, if I go back to A0/B0 and decide to do something else instead of the merge on either component, things start to become hazy in terms of recording history.  My intuition, is that I would ditch my merge history once I changed either A0 or B0.

My specific questions are:
1 - what would a user expect (git paradigm, google doc paradigm, etc.)?
2 - are there any common paradigms to deal with this more complex paradigm (I don't think that the Momento or Command Pattern deal with these cases [split/merge] well)? 
3 - is there an easier / less sophisticated way to deal with such patterns that might be "good enough"?

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: `My intuition, is that I would ditch my merge history once I changed either A0 or B0.` The first versions of many software only allowed one undo (on the Mac, for example). Users find ways to save various copies when there is not enough undo support, and they tend to complain about it. You could take the KISS approach and wait for users to complain after using it, then add it later. *Listening to users is a tricky thing*: http://blog.codinghorror.com/i-repeat-do-not-listen-to-your-users/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is difficult to answer without knowing more about what your software is doing so I'll try to be general.

**1 - what would a user expect (git paradigm, google doc paradigm, etc.)?**

Who is your user?  You mentioned that this is genomics software.  Do your users have biology backgrounds or software backgrounds.  In my experience, biologists often have different expectations than software developers.

Before you start going down the wrong path, you should ask your users what they expect.  We can't answer the question, only they can.  Frequent communication with your users and good requirements gathering are key to delivering successful software.

**2 - are there any common paradigms to deal with this more complex paradigm (I don't think that the Momento or Command Pattern deal with these cases [split/merge] well)?**

Again, without knowing exactly what your are splitting or merging, I can't give a definitive answer but the `Command` Pattern is capable of executing very complex tasks.  There is nothing saying that the undo/merge command has to be the exact opposite of the redo/split command..  You may also want to look into the `State` Pattern or a combination of `State` and `Command` where each state creates different commands.

**3 - is there an easier / less sophisticated way to deal with such patterns that might be "good enough"?**

`Memento` might be good enough or perhaps some kind of serialization.  It might be simpler to save each version into a temp file and undo/redo operations just restore from those temp files.

Comment: Point (1) is well-stated and probably the most important.  I will update when I have more info.   I am trying to both track and move through history for entities (in this case transcripts) separately, which is compounded by the entities splitting and merging.   I use the [momento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) right now, which works great for managing an originator that does not merge/split.   I also need to split 1 originator into 2, or merge 2 originators into 1.    The command pattern would be ideal, but its not really possible here.

Comment: I think the question / answer is, if you undo to a certain point and choose a different history path, should you retain the alternate history?  The answer is typically no, whether you do a split or a merge.   Thanks for getting my head around the problem.

Comment: @NathanDunn no problem.  And to answer your question, you should only keep the "current" history timeline, not any alternate histories.